# OS X El Capitan stuck on Beta without Software Update

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, software-update

I have an issue with OS X El Capitan.

I just noticed in "About this Mac" that my version is "10.11 Beta (15A279b)" but in Software Update I have no option to upgrade to GM.

Should I just download the GM and perform an upgrade or would I have to wipe my entire system?

I have to upgrade since It's not possible uploading new iOS / OSX apps to the App Store with a Beta.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - Software update doesn't show there's an update.
But if you download the full installer, it will automatically update your Beta to GM without any issues so far. seems to work :)